# Why variables declared in class, defined in function can be initialized?

Tags: c++

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
    void show_all(){std::cout << x1 << ", " << y1 << ", " << z1 << std::endl;}
    void show_uninit();
private:
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int z1;
};
void A::show_uninit()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    std::cout << i << ", " << j << ", " << k << std::endl;
    return ;
}
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.show_all();
    a.show_uninit();
    return 0;
}
```

Which got the the following warning after compiled:

```
$ g++ -Wall test_construction.cpp
test_construction.cpp: In member function ‘void A::show_uninit()’:
test_construction.cpp:22:18: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     std::cout << i << ", " << j << ", " << k << std::endl;
                  ^
test_construction.cpp:22:31: warning: ‘j’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     std::cout << i << ", " << j << ", " << k << std::endl;
                               ^
test_construction.cpp:22:44: warning: ‘k’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     std::cout << i << ", " << j << ", " << k << std::endl;
                                        ^
```

My understanding is the member a.x1, a.y1 and a.z1 should have got the same warnings that i, j and k got because object "a" was defined in function main() by stating "A a;", though it was declared in class out of any function. 
Thanks!

Comment: Because the compiler isn't smart enough to warn you about it. Rest assured, they *will* have unpredictable values like any other uninitialized variable.

Comment: you are correct, the compiler should have warned you about it. since you didn't call a constructor, the members are not initialized, you could have also called the default constructor: A a{};    as we all know, if there is no one, the compiler would generate it for you, giving default values to the member

Comment: @blade A constructor is called (conceptually, anyway). It simply did nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler isn't smart enough to generate a warning in this case.

Note: *The fact that the compiler doesn't produce any warnings or errors doesn't mean your code is right.* A lot of people don't realise this when they start programming.

Compilers aren't even required to generate warnings for `show_uninit`, although many do, because it's relatively easy to detect a local variable that is *never* initialized. (If `i`, `j` and `k` were initialized *sometimes*, you might not get a warning)

When executed, `show_all` will print unpredictable values, just like `show_uninit`.

Comment: g++ warns on `show_all()` as well with optimizations on, probably because of inlining.

Comment: When executed, `show_all` causes undefined behaviour which means that [anything can happen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).  It need not print anything or even execute at all.